Pinescript strategy taking many unwanted trades
Here is my Pinescript code for a strategy. Problem is that it is taking many un-wanted trades. Surprisingly those trades are opening and closing at the same candle.
It does take correct trades also but not sure why it is picking these un-wanted trades and opening and closing of those trades are in same candle.
//@version=6
strategy("Multi-Indicator Trading Strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

// Input parameters
psarStep = input.float(0.02, "PSAR Step")
psarMax = input.float(0.2, "PSAR Max")
vwmaLength = input(20, "VWMA Length")
supertrendPeriod = input(10, "Supertrend Period")
supertrendMultiplier = input.float(2.0, "Supertrend Multiplier")
profitTargetINR = input.float(1000, "Fixed Profit Target (INR)", step=1)
trailingStopPercentage = input.float(5, "Trailing Stop %", step=0.1)
trailingTakePercentage = input.float(5, "Trailing Take Profit %", step=0.1)

// Indicator Calculations
vwap = ta.vwap(close)
psar = ta.sar(psarStep, psarStep, psarMax)
vwma = ta.vwma(close, vwmaLength)
atr = ta.atr(supertrendPeriod)
[supertrend, supertrendDir] = ta.supertrend(supertrendMultiplier, supertrendPeriod)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

// Relaxed Volume condition
volumeCondition = volume + volume[1] >= 250

// Long Entry Conditions (relaxed)
longCondition = (close > vwap and close[1] > vwap) and (close > psar and close[1] > psar) and (close > vwma and close[1] > vwma) and (close > supertrend and close[1] > supertrend) and (rsi >= 50 and rsi <= 75) and (volumeCondition)
// Short Entry Conditions (relaxed)
shortCondition = (close < vwap and close[1] < vwap) and (close < psar and close[1] < psar) and (close < vwma and close[1] < vwma) and (close < supertrend and close[1] < supertrend) and (rsi >= 25 and rsi <= 40) and (volumeCondition)

// Initialize trailing stop and take profit variables
var float trailingStopLong = na
var float trailingTakeLong = na
var float trailingStopShort = na
var float trailingTakeShort = na

// Trade Entry Logic
if (longCondition and strategy.position_size == 0)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    trailingStopLong := close * (1 - trailingStopPercentage / 100)
    trailingTakeLong := close * (1 + trailingTakePercentage / 100)

if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size == 0)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    trailingStopShort := close * (1 + trailingStopPercentage / 100)
    trailingTakeShort := close * (1 - trailingTakePercentage / 100)

// Update trailing stop and take profit levels for long positions
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    trailingStopLong := math.max(trailingStopLong, close * (1 - trailingStopPercentage / 100))
    trailingTakeLong := math.max(trailingTakeLong, close * (1 + trailingTakePercentage / 100))
    // Exit if price hits trailing stop or take profit
    if (close <= trailingStopLong)
        strategy.close("Long", comment="Trailing Stop Hit")
    if (close >= trailingTakeLong)
        strategy.close("Long", comment="Trailing Take Profit Hit")
    // Exit if profit reaches ₹100
    //if (strategy.netprofit >= profitTargetINR)
      //  strategy.close("Long", comment="Fixed Profit Target Hit")

// Update trailing stop and take profit levels for short positions
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    trailingStopShort := math.min(trailingStopShort, close * (1 + trailingStopPercentage / 100))
    trailingTakeShort := math.min(trailingTakeShort, close * (1 - trailingTakePercentage / 100))
    // Exit if price hits trailing stop or take profit
    if (close >= trailingStopShort)
        strategy.close("Short", comment="Trailing Stop Hit")
    if (close <= trailingTakeShort)
        strategy.close("Short", comment="Trailing Take Profit Hit")
    // Exit if profit reaches ₹100
    //if (strategy.netprofit >= profitTargetINR)
      //  strategy.close("Short", comment="Fixed Profit Target Hit")

// Logic to close all trades at 15:20
closeTimeHour = 15
closeTimeMinute = 20
//if (hour == closeTimeHour and minute >= closeTimeMinute and strategy.position_size != 0)
  //  strategy.close_all(comment="Closed at 15:20")

// Plot indicators for visual reference
plot(vwap, color=color.black, linewidth=2, title="VWAP")
plot(psar, color=color.red, title="PSAR")
plot(vwma, color=color.yellow, title="VWMA")
plot(supertrend, color=color.purple, title="Supertrend")

Please advise. Thanks

Sorry! I missed the piece of code for long and short entry builder:
// Long Entry Conditions
longCondition = (close > vwap and close[1] > vwap) and (close > psar and close[1] > psar) and (close > vwma and close[1] > vwma) and (close > supertrend and close[1] > supertrend) and (rsi >= 50 and rsi <= 75) and (volumeCondition)
// Short Entry Conditions
shortCondition = (close < vwap and close[1] < vwap) and (close < psar and close[1] < psar) and (close < vwma and close[1] < vwma) and (close < supertrend and close[1] < supertrend) and (rsi >= 25 and rsi <= 40) and (volumeCondition)

Please edit and post the code correctly

done. please check if you get a chance

for entry_orders, try this:
if (longCondition and strategy.position_size <= 0)

for SL & TP use strategy.exit() whit stop & limit
strategy.exit(
  id                 = 'Long Exit',
  from_entry         = 'Long',
  stop               = trailingStopLong,
  limit              = trailingTakeLong)

for debug, plot trailingTake & trailingStop
//@version=6
strategy("Multi-Indicator Trading Strategy", overlay=true)

// Input parameters
psarStep = input.float(0.02, "PSAR Step")
psarMax = input.float(0.2, "PSAR Max")
vwmaLength = input(20, "VWMA Length")
supertrendPeriod = input(10, "Supertrend Period")
supertrendMultiplier = input.float(2.0, "Supertrend Multiplier")
profitTargetINR = input.float(1000, "Fixed Profit Target (INR)", step=1)
trailingStopPercentage = input.float(5, "Trailing Stop %", step=0.1)
trailingTakePercentage = input.float(5, "Trailing Take Profit %", step=0.1)

// Indicator Calculations
vwap = ta.vwap(close)
psar = ta.sar(psarStep, psarStep, psarMax)
vwma = ta.vwma(close, vwmaLength)
atr = ta.atr(supertrendPeriod)
[supertrend, supertrendDir] = ta.supertrend(supertrendMultiplier, supertrendPeriod)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

// Relaxed Volume condition
volumeCondition = volume + volume[1] >= 250

// Long Entry Conditions (relaxed)
longCondition = (close > vwap and close[1] > vwap) and (close > psar and close[1] > psar) and (close > vwma and close[1] > vwma) and (close > supertrend and close[1] > supertrend) and (rsi >= 50 and rsi <= 75) and (volumeCondition)
// Short Entry Conditions (relaxed)
shortCondition = (close < vwap and close[1] < vwap) and (close < psar and close[1] < psar) and (close < vwma and close[1] < vwma) and (close < supertrend and close[1] < supertrend) and (rsi >= 25 and rsi <= 40) and (volumeCondition)

// Initialize trailing stop and take profit variables
var float trailingStopLong = na
var float trailingTakeLong = na
var float trailingStopShort = na
var float trailingTakeShort = na

// Trade Entry Logic
if (longCondition and strategy.position_size <= 0)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    trailingStopLong  := close * (1 - trailingStopPercentage / 100)
    trailingTakeLong  := close * (1 + trailingTakePercentage / 100)
    trailingStopShort := na
    trailingTakeShort := na

if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    trailingStopShort := close * (1 + trailingStopPercentage / 100)
    trailingTakeShort := close * (1 - trailingTakePercentage / 100)
    trailingStopLong  := na
    trailingTakeLong  := na

// Update trailing stop and take profit levels for long positions
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    trailingStopLong := math.max(trailingStopLong, close * (1 - trailingStopPercentage / 100))
    trailingTakeLong := math.max(trailingTakeLong, close * (1 + trailingTakePercentage / 100))
    strategy.exit(
      id                 = 'Long Exit',
      from_entry         = 'Long',
      stop               = trailingStopLong,
      limit              = trailingTakeLong,
      comment_loss       = 'trailingStopLong',
      comment_profit     = 'trailingTakeLong')

// Update trailing stop and take profit levels for short positions
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    trailingStopShort := math.min(trailingStopShort, close * (1 + trailingStopPercentage / 100))
    trailingTakeShort := math.min(trailingTakeShort, close * (1 - trailingTakePercentage / 100))
    strategy.exit(
      id                 = 'Short Exit',
      from_entry         = 'Short',
      stop               = trailingStopShort,
      limit              = trailingTakeShort,
      comment_loss       = 'trailingStopShort',
      comment_profit     = 'trailingTakeShort')

// Logic to close all trades at 15:20
closeTimeHour = 15
closeTimeMinute = 20
//if (hour == closeTimeHour and minute >= closeTimeMinute and strategy.position_size != 0)
  //  strategy.close_all(comment="Closed at 15:20")

// Plot indicators for visual reference
plot(vwap, color=color.black, linewidth=2, title="VWAP")
plot(psar, color=color.red, title="PSAR")
plot(vwma, color=color.yellow, title="VWMA")
plot(supertrend, color=color.purple, title="Supertrend")

plot (
   trailingTakeLong,
  'trailingTakeLong',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.olive, 0),
  style          = plot.style_steplinebr)
plot (
   trailingStopLong,
  'trailingStopLong',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.maroon, 0),
  style          = plot.style_steplinebr)
plot (
   trailingTakeShort,
  'trailingTakeShort',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.olive, 0),
  style          = plot.style_steplinebr)
plot (
   trailingStopShort,
  'trailingStopShort',
  linewidth      = 2,
  color          = color.new(color.maroon, 0),
  style          = plot.style_steplinebr)



Thank you very much !! This worked as expected.
